# Can Benign Transposition be used on your familiar as a form of teleportation?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, familiars

I might be thinking of Pathfinder, but if familiars in DnD can teleport to their masters, would it be possible to use Benign Transposition to switch places with your familiar, then have it return to you, as an early form of teleportation?

Comment: You are thinking of Pathfinder. Familiars in 3.5 cannot natively teleport to their masters. Still a valid approach, but the familiar has to return the long way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes

It’ll work. I’d be *very* careful about where you’re sending that Familiar though, seeing as it is going to cost you a lot of XP if it dies.